# A rest service using spring 2 and jersey, unable to get response for some consumers

Tags: spring-boot, jersey-2.0, spring2.x

We have an application that uses asyncresponse and writes the data into a stream.

I upgraded to spring2 from 1.5. 
And not sure if it could be releated but now with postman I get this error "Unexpected end of file".

Even in a java client , I get error "java.IO.EOFException: Unexpected end of zlib input stream".

But I get expected result in a curl command.

Now I suspect, this could be something either with user-agent or somewhere in spring2 or jersey , I need to set some properties to get rid of this.

There is no security , I excluded SecurityAutoConfiguration.java, in case somewhere it checks some user-agent.

Because of error I see in java client, I tried with server.compression.enabled=false (which is default anyway), but no luck.

I suppose I need to edit the question.
It seems there is some issue using StreamingOutput using spring2x. This is not streaming which I assumes results in all of above stated issues.

Any help is appreciated.